# Google sheets, Array Formula + SUMIFS within a date range and additional criteria

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eAaMYJBPVwb9xLFNY3KKVuN_MdJLY1iFN7fL4ORHdCc/edit?usp=sharing

Formula in D1.

```
=ArrayFormula({"Sum of data O "; if(len(A2:A130),sumifs(data!O2:O130,data!N2:N130, ">="&validations!$B$1&"", data!N2:N130, "<"&validations!$B$2&"", data!G2:G130, "<>RLT", data!K2:K130, A2:A130),)})
```

I know arrays don't work with sumifs.
I have one solution with a query, but it's not the prettiest one.

Can anyone come up with a solution using Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sumifs(data!O:O,data!N:N, ">="&validations!B1&"", data!N:N, "<"&validations!B2&"", data!G:G, "<>RLT", data!K:K, Σ))))
```

[image]